# Cross Products vs Permutations vs Combinations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I was studying about permutations and combinations, and I got a sense that...

A. We do cross products when the order matters (or each decision is different) and we can reuse each choice every time, as in boolean logical functions: We have 4 decisions (TT, TF, FT, FF), and 2 choices (T, F)... so 2 x 2 x 2 x 2.

B. We do permutations when the order matters, but we can't reuse choices. As in ranking members in a set. Therefore, we use factorials.

C. For combinations, the order doesn't matter, and we can't reuse choices.

Is this intuition sensible?

P.S. Are there cases where the order doesn't matter, but we can reuse choices? I can't think of one.

Comment: "cross product" is a technical term in mathematics for something very different than anything having to do with counting choices – it's a way to combine two vectors in 3-space to get another such vector.

Comment: "*Are there cases where the order doesn't matter but we can reuse choices?*"  Yes.  That type of scenario can be counted using the technique of [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  For more information on that and several other basic counting problems, see [The Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way) on wikipedia where we talk about the answers to various balls and bins questions where we either require bins receive at most 1 ball, at least 1 ball, or any number, balls and/or bins are distinguishable vs indistinguishable, etc...